# Varnish as Reverse Proxy Server for Rubygems

Tags: reverse-proxy, varnish

I want to setup a cache server for Rubygems, as I'm currently based in Vietnam and the international internet connections are pretty slow. I have been trying to get this done via Varnish, but after hours of googling and trying various things I'm still stuck and can't get it to work properly.

### My goal

This a sample request group when I'm installing a gem:

```
GET http://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
```

I want to setup a reverse proxy cache server (e.g. rubygems.mydomain.com) where I can perform the following request and the cache server would follow any redirects internally.

```
rubygems.mydomain.com/latest_specs.4.8.gz
```

The redirect location will link to various domains (some rubygems subdomains, Amazon S3, rubygems mirror).

### Current State

After fiddling around with nginx, I found [this blog post](http://sillyadmin.blogspot.com/2012/10/varnish-for-multiple-hosts-following.html) which is pretty close what I wanna achieve. However, I have too little knowledge about how Varnish works to get it working properly.

That's my current config file

```
import std;

backend rubygems {
    .host = "rubygems.org";
    .port = "80";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    std.syslog(180, "RECV: " + req.http.host + req.url);
    if (!req.url  ~ "^http") {
      std.syslog(180, "FETCH");
      set req.backend = rubygems;
      return (lookup);
    }
}

sub vcl_fetch {
    if (beresp.status == 302) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magic-Redirect = "1";
        return(deliver);
    }
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.http.X-Magic-Redirect == "1") {
        set req.url = obj.http.Location;
        return (restart);
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magic-Redirect == "1") {
        unset resp.http.X-Magic-Redirect;
        return(restart);
    }
    return(deliver);
}
```

I can perform a request, but it responds with an error:

```
curl -is http://localhost:8080/latest_specs.4.8.gz
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Varnish
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Retry-After: 5
Content-Length: 376
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sat, 01 Feb 2014 02:33:47 GMT
X-Varnish: 933109322
Age: 1
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>302 Found</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Error 302 Found</h1>
    <p>Found</p>
    <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
    <p>XID: 933109322</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Varnish cache server</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and that's the corresponding syslog output for the request:

```
Jan 31 18:33:46 precise64 varnishd[2387]: RECV: localhost:8080/latest_specs.4.8.gz
Jan 31 18:33:46 precise64 varnishd[2387]: FETCH
Jan 31 18:33:47 precise64 varnishd[2387]: RECV: localhost:8080/latest_specs.4.8.gz
Jan 31 18:33:47 precise64 varnishd[2387]: FETCH
Jan 31 18:33:47 precise64 varnishd[2387]: RECV: localhost:8080http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
```

So, the request to Rubygems is working fine, but following the redirect does not work as expected. I would be glad if somebody could point me in the right direction.

Comment: I think you're missing an adequate backend once the request have been restarted.

Anyway, you should also change fill req.http.host and req.url appropiately when following the redirect

Answer (score 2):

At this point when you will receive a 302 status from your rubygems backend, you have to make a request again at the new location specify by the HTTP header **Location** in the response.

You should end up with something like that:

```
vcl_fetch {
   if (beresp.status == 302) {  /* The content is on another location */

      /* First change the host of the request*/
      set req.http.host = regsub(regsub(beresp.http.Location, "^http://", ""), "^([^/]+)/.*$", "\1");

      /* Then change the url of the request */
      set req.url = regsub(beresp.http.Location, "^http://[^/]+/(.*)$", "/\1");
      return (restart);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I contacted the author of [angry-caching-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angry-caching-proxy), she responded:

> Unfortunately your concern is correct. I have left the company two years ago for which I wrote it for - meaning my interest in maintaining it is fairly low. And it seems that nobody else has picked it up there...

Answer (score 0):

If you get that working, please share.
Especially whether it works with the bundler dependency protocol.

There is some good information [here](https://github.com/mumoshu/docker-squid-gem-proxy)
Alternatively, you may want to take a look at [geminabox](https://github.com/geminabox/geminabox)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is https://www.npmjs.org/package/angry-caching-proxy which provides a proxy that will cache the gems on the way through.